# How to enable an Ethernet interface at boot on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-machine

I have a VM which is connected to a network with DHCP etc.

Whenever I boot the VM the virtual Ethernet connection is DOWN.  I need to log in by console and run `dhclient eth0` to enable it.  Every time.  I wish to enable `eth0` upon boot.

This is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
UUID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-5555555555555555
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HOTPLUG=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DHCPV6C=yes
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
USERCTL=no
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
DNS1=9.9.9.9
DNS2=1.1.1.1
```

I thought that `ONBOOT=yes` was the important bit here but it is ignored completely.  Who reads this file?  Perhaps that's the culprit.

The `HOTPLUG=yes` I only added in the hope that this would help (perhaps interface coming up late...) but it does not.

I set `NM_CONTROLLED=no` because I have no NetworkManager service (server, no user-management allowed or needed).

> My question is: What is wrong with my config file or what setting
>   would help?

Comment: @marcio: Thanks for the edit, that's better. I thought "I have no NetworkManager service" would suffice but that is apparently too unclear or hidden.

Comment: Wouldn't a cron rule do it ?

Comment: @X.LINK Thanks. The trigger to start the network connection should not be time but the boot process, so a `systemd` script would be more appropriate. However, I would consider that a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: `cron` rules done with `crontab -e` can be set to be boot-based with an `@reboot` string (e.g. `@reboot dhclient eth0`), which will make things not depend on systemd and will works on wider systems.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your config file is not clear for me.

But, using CenOS 8, a suitable setting to help you could be to use NetworkManager, since network scripts are deprecated:

[RHEL 8 Deprecated Network Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483354/rhel-8-deprecated-network-scripts)

- setting connection.autoconnect property to true.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no NetworkManager in my system, and there won't be. My question was what was wrong with my config file or what setting would help.  What have people done before NetworkManager?  In my memory these files worked without it!

Comment: Could you try to create and test a new `ifcfg-eth0` with less directives to debug it?

Comment: Thanks, I will try the `network-scripts` package. I cannot reboot the server too often (in pre-production) but will check back in the next few days. Too bad companies make server hardening more difficult these days by requiring tools that require a dozen other packages recursively just for simple things like `ip l s up eth0` upon boot. May write my own `systemd` service if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cron` rule for that.

Just edit/create your rule with the `crontab -e` command, choose your editor (be careful, crontab will only ask this one. Also, nano is the simplest) then append the file with an `@reboot` line followed by your command, which in your case will be: `@reboot dhclient eth0`.

And now, everytime you boot, your `dhclient eth0` will be ran.

Do note that @reboot, despite its name, has (almost) nothing to do with reboot and will always works when you're booting from zero.

Comment: Granted that's more of a workaround, but so does a systemd script that is far less flexible.