# Adding second IP to RHEL 8 virtual machine

Tags: rhel, networkmanager

I have an existing RHEL8 virtual machine used for running httpd and a single virtualhost. I need to add a second IP/virtual host and am running into an issue.  My understanding is that NetworkManager [still parses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483387) network-scripts.

The existing IP is configured as:

```
[user@box]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens3
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=ens3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.111
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.2
DNS1=xxx.xxx.1.1
ZONE=drop
```

I created a second script set up with the new IP:

```
[user@box]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens4 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens4
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=ens4
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.222
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.2
DNS1=xxx.xxx.1.1
ZONE=drop
```

I then restarted NetworkManager with

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

But I'm not seeing the new device named ens4 listed, just the existing IP (ens3)

```
[user@box]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.111/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 scope global noprefixroute ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Device ens3 works fine.

The existing bridge from the host machine works since device ens3 works fine (I can view site content, ssh to machine, ect). So I'm not super sure this is a VM host setup issue.

What step(s) am I missing to add a second IP to RHEL8? Is the process different when the server is virtual?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a misunderstanding about how NetworkManager works. In Networkkanager you configure connection profiles (e.g. in form of ifcfg files). They are just a bunch of settings for setting up an interface. To make the configuration effective and configure the network on your system, activate the desired profile.

> systemctl restart NetworkManager

Restarting NetworkManager is almost never the right thing to do. In particular not when you want to apply some changes to IP configuration, because when you restart NetworkManager it tries to not change the IP configuration so that you could restart it remotely (although, that is probably still a dangerous thing to do if something goes wrong and you cut yourself off).

Anyway. If you modify profiles on disk, then reload them with `nmcli connection reload` or `nmcli connection load "$FILENAME"`. The effect of that is similar to `nmcli connection modify` (in the sense, that both end up modifying NetworkManager's understanding of the profile, the former by loading it from disk, the latter by writing it to disk). Check the result with `nmcli connection` and `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"` or `nmcli -o connection show "$PROFILE"`.

Note that modifications of a profile only become effective after you activate the profile the next time. What I mean, is "the modifications to the profile" become effective immediately to the profile, but the runtime configuration only changes by (re)activating a profile. See the profiles with `nmcli connection` and the runtime state with `nmcli device`. Activate the desired profile with `nmcli connection up` $PROFILE"`.

---

But the real answer to your question is probably the following:

Your text has the title "adding a second IP address", but then you proceed to create a new profile for an `ens4` interface. Then, you check `ip addr` output and don't see `ens4`. Creating a profile does not create a network interface. You need (virtualized?) hardware and the driver loaded, so that you see the interface in `ip link` (or `nmcli device`) before NetworkManager can do something with it.

From the title, I would have thought you would rather want to add a second IP address to the existing profile. Do that with`nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" +ipv4.addresses "10.0.0.111/8"`, check the result with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"` and (re)activate the right profile. Of course, you can also edit the ifcfg file and reload it.

Comment: Thanks, I actually learned not to issue the restart to NetworkManager earlier today after posting. I realized that a second profile (or even alias like many of us used to do such as ens4:1, ens4:2, ect) is also not a good idea. Instead, I simply added IPADDR1 xxx.xxx.xxx.222 and PREFIX1 xx to the existing ens3 interface file. I deleted the ens4 file. rebooted, I now have my two IPs active for this machine.

Answer (score 0):

While @thaller's answer is probably technically better, here's what I did that was pretty quick and easy.

I simply edited the existing ens3 interface to add:

```
IPADDR1 xxx.xxx.xxx.222 
PREFIX1 xx
```

I put this just below the existing IPADDR and PREFIX lines. If I needed additional IPs, I would continue the sequence of IPADDR2, IPADDR3, ect.

I then deleted the ens4 file as it is not needed anymore.

After reboot, both IPs are now active for this machine.